# Session variable gets destroyed before its session timeout n jsp

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

```
 <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
```

This above web.xml config code should kill the session variables when the Web Application is idle for exactly 60 minutes.

But in my project the session variables are destroyed before 60 minutes. For example I stored one session variable in one `jsp` and it is accessed in other `jsp`s  but the problem is, sometimes the stored session variables gets destroyed before the specified timeout value and shows `null` value for that session variable.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Save it to a database. An hour is quite long time to maintain a session. Imagine having lots of users, the server is gonna run out of memory quite fast.

Comment: @BorisPavlović what if i go with application or page context objects in jsp, will it fix this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it will be saved in the memory, not persisted on a disk.

Comment: @BorisPavlović  i tell you the scenario of my project please suggest me which is the right way to do that, we have different types of user roles and based on the user role the menu level should vary so what i did was i created user_role field in DB then i fetched and stored that field in one jsp and stored that user_role in session. In other jsp's i process that session variable and based on that variable i will display the menu. since this session gets destroyed the User_role variable becomes NULL .

Comment: Are you perfectly sure that the session variable gets destroyed? Are you maybe clearing it yourself?

Comment: It is hard to guess what is going on without reading your code and the web container configuration.